# Sacar la longitud/tamaño o numero de "hijos" de un nodo en Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Actualmente estoy trabajado con Firebase y todo muy bien.
Pero no he encontrado como es que puedo sacar de manera sencilla y rapida la longitud/tamaño de un nodo. Por ejemplo:

```
Usuarios
  Masculino
   -Juan
   -Pedro
   -Carlos
   -Pepito

 Femenino
   -Maria
   -Lizbeth
```

Como es que puedo sacar el numero de "hijos" que tiene el nodo "Masculino"/"Femenino"?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola @AlanOliver, sin ver tu código y como tienes definida tu clase nodo es imposible que podamos ayudarte. Deberías poner tu código y si has intentado algo decir lo que has intentado y donde te ha fallado. Edita tu pregunta y re hazla de acuerdo a las normas del sitio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

es muy sencillo, se utiliza `getChildrenCount()`

primero referencias al nodo padre de los hijos

por ejemplo

```
mDatabase.child("Usuarios").child("Masculino").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    long numHijos = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("Fallo la lectura: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

Para hacerlo de otra forma pasando uno por uno como lo solicita un comentario abajo podemos hacer lo siguiente

```
mDatabase.child("Usuarios").child("Masculino").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Log.e(snap.getKey(),snap.getChildrenCount() + "");
    }
}

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("Fallo la lectura: " + databaseError.getCode());
      }
    });
```

puedes hacer lo mismo con femenino, saludos

Comment: Esta excelente, es justo lo que necesiaba. Ya habia encontrado otra forma, pero esta es mucho mas directa y facil. Muchas gracias!

Comment: perfecto que te haya servido, cualquier otra cosa me preguntas

Comment: como puedo poner ese contador por cada interacción?

Comment: ahi te edite la respuesta @valverde

Answer (score 1):

la respuesta que propuso @Gastón Saillén es perfecta a lo que buscaba. Solo quiero comparti el metodo que encontre yo mismo. En esta se obtienen todos los key (Nombres del nodo) que tienes. Entonces simplemente se pone un contador por cada interaccion.

Aqui se utiliza el metodo endAt(), en el cual se especifica hasta donde se recorrera. Este debe de estar en la base de datos en la lista que deseas sacar la longitud.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); //Se crea una instancia para acceder a los datos de Firebase Database Realtime
    final DatabaseReference usuarioRef = database.getReference("Masculino"); //Se especifica a que archivo se hace referencia

    usuarioRef.orderByKey().endAt("Pepito").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            Toast.makeText(Eventos.this, dataSnapshot.getKey(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

        // ...
    });
```